# No overload matches this call Error on Input Tag When Using 'size' Props - Typescript and Styled-component

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, styled-components

I'm not entirely sure what's happening with my code. As you can see in the styles file, I'm declaring size as a **string**, but for some reason, when I hover over size, it shows **(parameter) size: never**. I have no idea where this "never" type is coming from.
I assumed it might be some kind of default type coming from styled-components. Any ideas on how I can override this or fix it somehow?

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledInput = styled.input<{
  size: string;
}>`
  ${({ size }) => size === 'small' && 'background-color: red;'}
`;
`
```

```
const StyledInput: StyledComponent<"input", DefaultTheme, {
    size: string;
}, never>
```

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { size: never; color?: string | undefined; form?: string | undefined; slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; title?: string | undefined; pattern?: string | undefined; ... 291 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"input", DefaultTheme, { size: string; }, never, "input", "input">): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"input", DefaultTheme, { ...; }, never, "input", "input">, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(2341, 9): The expected type comes from property 'size' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { size: never; color?: string | undefined; form?: string | undefined; slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; ... 293 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'
index.d.ts(2341, 9): The expected type comes from property 'size' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { size: never; color?: string | undefined; form?: string | undefined; slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; ... 293 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'
```